# adding html url hyperlink on Angular JS 1

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, innerhtml

I am working on a non-profit project. The website is run on Angular JS version 1, and I would like to add html hyperlink on my javascript file. It’s currently coded as text `var description =`  and I have tried innerhtml and didn’t work. It's currently being treated as a text string.

Here’s my link to the file where the codes are https://github.com/zcjtshy/zcjtshy.github.io/blob/master/app/services/hcwStories.data.js [1](https://github.com/zcjtshy/zcjtshy.github.io)

```
var description = '#I want to insert a hyperlink here' 
var stories = []
export default {
  stories,
  description,}
```

Comment: I feel for you that you're not a developer by trade, but it's really impossible to help you without you having included your code as a [mre] - we have no idea how this `description` variable is used later. It's somewhat helpful you've included a link to your GitHub repository, but nobody here is going to go through *all* your code to pinpoint this one file you need help with. [ask]

Comment: Add your HTML where you want to display said `description`. See [ngHref](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngHref).